# Statistical test for comparing cutoff values in independent samples

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, roc, auc

A binary diagnostic test currently uses the same cutoff value (level of biomarker) for males and females when determining disease vs non-disease (D+/D-). However, I suspect that the level of biomarker corresponding to D+/D- between males and females is different. Hence, different cutoff values for determining D+/D- may be warranted. I would like to perform a statistical test to investigate this. I have have quantitative data of the biomarker as well as the final diagnosis (D+/D-) for each patient, as determined by a different test (imaging).

I am considering the following: define an "optimal cutoff value" as the greatest level of biomarker that still achieves >95% sensitivity for each group. Then test the null hypothesis that there is no difference between "optimal cutoff values" between males and females.

Is this a valid test for the problem purposed? What statistical test can be used to determine if the "optimized cutoff values" calculated from male and female samples are statistically different? Alternatively, how is the confidence interval of a point on the ROC curve calculated?